# Render custom PDFView in PDF with swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios-pdfkit, apple-pdfkit

I’m showing a PDF page in UIView’s subview using PDFKit along with some UILabel and UIImageView. At a time I’m only showing one page in PDFView. Users can change the size and position of this PDFView.

```
class ResizablePDFView: PDFView {
        
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
    }
    
    override func draw(_ layer: CALayer, in ctx: CGContext) {
        let isPDF = !UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds().isEmpty
        if isPDF {
            if let document = self.document, document.pageCount > 0, let page = document.page(at: 0) {
                ctx.saveGState()
                ctx.scaleBy(x: 1, y: -1)
                ctx.translateBy(x: 0, y: -bounds.size.height)
                let pageBounds = page.bounds(for: .mediaBox)
                ctx.scaleBy( x: bounds.size.width / pageBounds.size.width, y: bounds.size.height / pageBounds.size.height)
                ctx.translateBy(x: -pageBounds.origin.x, y: -pageBounds.origin.y)
                page.draw(with: .mediaBox, to: ctx)
                ctx.restoreGState()
            }
        }else {
            super.draw(layer, in: ctx)
        }
    }
    
}

class ResizableLabelView: UILabel {
    
    func setup() {
        self.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
        self.textColor = UIColor.systemBlue
    }
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
    }
    
    override func draw(_ layer: CALayer, in ctx: CGContext) {
        let isPDF = !UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds().isEmpty
        if isPDF {
            draw(bounds)
        }else {
            super.draw(layer, in: ctx)
        }
    }
    
}
```

CanvasView setup,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var canvasView: UIView!
    var pdfView: ResizablePDFView!
    var label: ResizableLabelView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        
        self.canvasView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 400, height: 573)))
        self.canvasView.center = self.view.center
        self.canvasView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.view.addSubview(self.canvasView)
        
        self.setupPDF()
        self.setupLabel()
    }
    
    func setupPDF() {
        
        self.pdfView = ResizablePDFView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: self.canvasView.frame.size))
        self.pdfView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.canvasView.addSubview(self.pdfView)
        
        self.pdfView.autoScales = false
        self.pdfView.displayMode = .singlePage
        self.pdfView.displaysPageBreaks = false
        self.pdfView.pageBreakMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        self.pdfView.pageShadowsEnabled = false
        
        if let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sample_pdf", withExtension: "pdf") {
            if let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: file) {
                let pageNumber: Int = 0
                if let page = pdfDocument.page(at: pageNumber) {
                    
                    let pageDocument = PDFDocument()
                    pageDocument.insert(page, at: 0)
                    self.pdfView.document = pageDocument
                    
                    self.pdfView.minScaleFactor = self.pdfView.scaleFactorForSizeToFit
                    self.pdfView.maxScaleFactor = self.pdfView.scaleFactorForSizeToFit
                    self.pdfView.scaleFactor = self.pdfView.scaleFactorForSizeToFit
                    
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    func setupLabel() {
        self.label = ResizableLabelView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 200, height: 50))
        self.label.setup()
        self.label.text = "Sample Text"
        self.label.sizeToFit()
        self.canvasView.addSubview(self.label)
    }
        
}
```

now, I'm creating the PDF from canvasView

```
    @IBAction func exportButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let filePath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("Exported_PDF.pdf")
        
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(filePath.path, .zero, [kCGPDFContextCreator as String: "PDF Export Demo App"])
        guard let canvas = self.canvasView else { return }
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(canvas.bounds, nil)
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        canvas.setNeedsDisplay()
        canvas.layer.render(in: context)
        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
        
        print(filePath)
    }
```

Now, This will render UILabel and UIImageView in PDF properly without rasterization and selectable text, but **It does not draw PDFView like original pdf with links**. What am I doing wrong here? how can I debug this issue?

[Resources:](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qLcGNGWxoXbWJnr6xBxueKjPHnfxYS6D?usp=drive_link)

I have tried to render PDFView using a custom PDFPage class, still getting the same result,
Also, tried drawing pages using different method

```
                ctx.scaleBy(x: 1, y: -1)
                ctx.translateBy(x: 0, y: -bounds.size.height)
                let pageBounds = page.bounds(for: .mediaBox)
                ctx.scaleBy( x: bounds.size.width / pageBounds.size.width, y: bounds.size.height / pageBounds.size.height)
                ctx.translateBy(x: -pageBounds.origin.x, y: -pageBounds.origin.y)
                draw(page, to: ctx)
```